# In oracle procedure, check if the row with primary key exists, if key already exists raise exception

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I have a procedure to insert a row in a table. I make various checks and if everything passes it inserts a row into the table.

One of the checks is to check if a row with primary key already exists in the table. If row with primary key already exists the procedure should be able to catch it and raise error.

What will be the best way to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than manually checking for a primary key conflict, why not let Oracle handle it for you. If you try and insert into a table, and a primary key conflict is found, Oracle raises the 'dup_val_on_index' exception. For example:

```
declare
begin
  --try and insert a value into the table
  insert into my_table (
    id,
    description
  ) values (
    1,
    'a duplicate id'
  );
exception
  when dup_val_on_index then
    dbms_output.put_line('a duplicate primary key');
    --your error handling logic here
    raise; --optionally re-raise the exception
end;
```

Comment: This way you catch not only PK violations, but every violation of a unique constraint

Comment: Sweet. This is what I was looking for. Thank you.